# Why won’t LED bulbs work in post lights?

Tags: led, post

My post lights had 3 incandescent bulbs each. I installed Feit LED bulbs and they wouldn’t come on. The lights are plugged into a timer; I removed the timer and they still wouldn’t turn on. When I took one LED bulb out and put back an incandescent bulb, that 1 bulb lit up. What’s going on and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Brand and model of the light fixtures may help resolve the issue.

Comment: Bulbs have two contact surfaces, usually the round side and a spot on the bottom.  With the power off at the breaker pull the little contact in the lamp socket up a bit and see if it helps.  Make sure the power is off since your fingers will be making contact with live power if not.  Do not trust the timer or switch to keep the power off.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Check the bulbs in a different fixture to be sure they work at all.

Manufacturing tolerances on some LED bulbs are horrible.

The center electrode may not be making contact with the socket, either due to poor geometry or badly formed threads, or overly fat sections too close above the threads as compared to a filament bulb.
With circuit power OFF you might be able to gently bend the center contact in the bulb socket up (too much and you'll likely break it, so be careful and don't overdo it.)

If you see the plastic housing of the bulb jamming on part of the fixture when you screw it in, (so, too fat) you probably need an LED bulb with a different shape, as it may be a LONG way out at the base (too far to safely bend the contact.)

Alternatively, get a different LED bulb with different geometry/construction. Some of the *faux filament* LEDs have glass envelopes of very similar geometry to actual filament bulbs, for instance.

A different brand of bulb might also work better. I'm familiar with Feit, I own a number of their LED products, and I would not put them at the top of the quality heap - they are cheap to buy and cheaply made as well. Sometimes that's expensive, in the end, when you have to replace them too much.

Comment: Gotta agree with Ecnerwal, Feit is not good stuff, Costco sells it and while Costco is a good company, some of the stuff they sell is sketchy. Made in China.   Try Phillips, I've had good luck with their stuff...still probably Made in China, but to higher specs, they are also made in various places throughout the world.

Comment: Yes, very common for older lights to be built expecting all bulbs to have long thin necks like an incandescent.  CFLs and LEDs like to put the *driver circuit* there which makes it fat. And that collides with part of the light, *feeling like* it's screwed in all the way, but it's really hanging up on something.